# Tower Defense Using All Paths

Tags: java

First of all I would like to mention that this is my very first post on stack overflow, so please warn me if I make something wrong.

I'm making a tower defense game for my project and I came across unusual problem.

I want to make some sort of path finding, but I'm not looking for the shortest way but I want to use all ways(paths)

[image: path]

As you can see the path on the picture my question if is there any algoritm or something like it so my enemies will go over all paths without returning back.

I am not sure if I'm enough precise, so if any additional explanation is needed I would like to explain it in details.

Thanks you all for helping me in further.

EDIT:

This is my random path chooser. (red indicates where my enemy go, yellow is where it should go)

[image: current path]

After I edit code and make it more clear to understand, I will upload source.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want a way to "calculate" all possible paths? How are the paths and the map represented? What have you done so far, and specifically what are you having trouble with? (This is not a code writing service.)

Comment: I don't need source code. I was just wondering for ideas how to solve the problem. So I have made some kind of "path finding", but problem is that I want my enemies to go on every possible path (not just shortest or longest etc.).

I made checkpoints so first cross is not a problem. Problem becomes on second cross and rest of them, as I dont know how to "send" them to finish, as they go backwards.

My checkpoints include all possible ways, where enemies can go including backwards (gray arrows on picture) and my problem is that i dont know how to block them.

Comment: And yes i want to calculate checkpoints before game start as i have map editor.

Comment: Well, nobody else knows how to block them either - since you haven't shared any code. You say you're looking for ideas, but you have the idea already - blocking.

Comment: Why not just have checkpoints around the map and have each enemy choose a random checkpoint to head to, once that enemy gets to the checkpoint it randomly chooses another

Comment: You need to embed the images... not just link to them... that's why I edited your question and added your image in....

Comment: Your question is not clear to me either

Comment: Every checkpoint has an array int[4]( each slot is used for 1 way). If value is 1 it means there is possible way for enemies to go, if is 0 there is no way. Problem is that i cant get my enemies to finish. Why? Some of them come to finish but not all, because i want them to go on every single possible path. But to FINISH, not going back on "old"(used) checkpoints(as gray arrows indicate it). So when i start game it calculates ALL possible ways for enemies and i need to block some of them so they wont circle in infinity.(second picture shows 1 example)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments are shown initially. Make it easy for people to help you. Also provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for advice! Will improve it. Appreciate it.